# Set DNS with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, dns

**What I am trying to accomplish:** I am trying to set the DNS address on my machine using powershell.

**Here is my code:**

```
$dnsserver = (,"192.168.0.5")
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name SetDNSServerSearchOrder -ArgumentList (,$dnsserver)
```

**I am using this as reference:**

[Using Invoke-WmiMethod to set the DNS servers](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/using-invoke-wmimethod-to-set-the-dns-servers/)

**The problem:** When I run the script, nothing changes. If I run the script and restart the machine, nothing happens. I am running the script on my local machine not remotely.

I am only wanting to add 1 DNS address.

Do I perhaps need to run as a different user or do something else special in order for this to work?

Comment: do you run an elevated powershell console ?

Comment: I do not believe so. Would that entail anything more than a 'cmd > right-click "Run As Admin"'?

Comment: It think you have not choose the best reference, have a look here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx

Comment: @Kayasax And that did it! I ran as Admin and boom. Thanks. If you want to put that in as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

managing network interfaces usualy require administrative rights, so you have to run your script in an elevaled powershell console.

Answer (score 8):

```
$DC = read-host "Please enter a primary DNS"
$Internet = read-host "Please enter secondary DNS"
$dns = "$DC", "$Internet"
```

For powershell 4:

```
#I know this one is sloppy, but will get the work done.

Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 -ServerAddresses ($DNS)
#I know this one is sloppy, but will get the work done.
```

For Powershell 1,2 and 3.

```
$Interface = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format T):Registering DNS $dns for $server" -ForegroundColor Green
$Interface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dns)
```

I plucked these off a script I wrote actually yesterday for a client that needed to set the DNS range for some-odd 200 Computers since the DC was failing.

If you are interested I can give you the whole script.
Point of the script is to run in a domain, and set every computer' DNS in the domain.

## Edit, Made a Better version of the executing part (PS4+)

This script should not show any errors, if it does something went wrong. Unlike previous script for ps4, it would always output several errors.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

#Set all DNS addresses needed.
write-verbose -Verbose "Set all DNS addresses needed."
$DC = "192.168.103.30"
$Internet = "8.8.8.8" #Google
$WorkRouter = "192.168.12.254"
$HomeRouter = "10.0.0.1"
$Possible = "192.168.1.1"
$Possible2 = "192.168.0.1"

#Combine addresses
write-verbose -Verbose "Combining DNS addresses."
$dns = "$DC", "$Internet", "$WorkRouter", "$HomeRouter", "$Possible", "$Possible2"

#Set network adapter ranges
write-verbose -Verbose "Setting network adapter ranges."

#Get Network adapters
write-Verbose -Verbose "Now checking available network adapters."
$Net = Get-NetAdapter | select ifIndex | ft -a | Out-File -FilePath C:/Netadapter.txt
$Net =  "C:/Netadapter.txt"

#Setting ranges to work with
$Ranges = (Get-Content $Net) -creplace "ifIndex", "" -creplace "-", "" | foreach {$_.Trim()} | Where { $_ } | Sort #| out-file C:/Netadapter.txt

#Execute DNS change
write-Warning -Verbose "Now executing DNS change to all available network adapters."
foreach ($range in $ranges)    {
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $range -ServerAddresses ($DNS)
}

write-verbose -Verbose "DNS Settings have been altered."
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have one network adapter you can use `Get-NetAdapter | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`

If you have many adapters you need to add name, for checking names run  `Get-NetAdapter`

`Get-NetAdapter  -Name "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`

Comment: You can more `serveraddresses` comma-separated?

Answer (score 7):

using the [`netsh.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx) program to script changes to the network interfaces is a great way to automate configuring them. Changing DNS is simple:

```
# turn on DHCP assigned DNS servers
netsh int ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp

# set a static DNS entry
netsh int ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.1
```

A few notes:

- You would need to change `"Local Area Connection"` to the name of the connection you are working with. Though this is generally the default - it may just work in your case. The DNS server address would also need to be specific to your scenario.
- Changing IP information usually requires elevated privileges, so make sure you are running PowerShell with elevated rights - by default Windows Vista and later launch PowerShell without elevating it. You will need to right click on it and choose "Run as admin".

Comment: This is also a great solution, however in my case I will not always know if "Local Area Connection" is the correct value.

Comment: For what it is worth: You can't rely on it always being index=7 in your WMI query either. Either value should be looked up or configured in advance.

Comment: Also true, good catch. I have since replaced it with '-Filter IPEnabled=TRUE'. (I had been trying a few different variations and at the time of posting that's what i was working with)

Comment: Can I add a second dns entry?

Answer (score 7):

This answer requires Powershell 4.

1. Run `Get-DNSClientServerAddress`. In the output, look for the Interface Index of the adapter you want to change.  You will need this in step 2.
2. *In an elevated prompt*, run `Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex ? –ServerAddresses ("8.8.8.8")` where `?` is the Interface Index of the interface you want to change DNS server address for (8.8.8.8 is Google's DNS - always a good standby, but change this to the address of whatever DNS server you want).
3. If you want to change the interface back to 'Obtain DNS server address automatically', *in an elevated prompt*, run `Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex ? -ResetServerAddresses` (Thanks to [this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/26/weekend-scripter-modify-dns-settings-via-windows-powershell.aspx) for this tip), again substituting the Interface Index you looked up in step 1 for `?`.

Comment: Steps 2 and 3: Instead of param `-interfaceindex` you can use `Get-NetAdapter  -Name "<e.g. vEthernet>" | set-dnsclientserv<...>` using `pipe` to make it better readable.

Answer (score 3):

```
$vmDNS1 = "192.0.2.1"
$vmDNS2 = "192.0.2.2"
$dns = "$vmDNS1", "$vmDNS2"

$Interface = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 
Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format T):Registering DNS $dns for $server" -ForegroundColor Green
$Interface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dns)
```

Using this from years. Used it against many datacenters to configure DNS on virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use.. PS 5.1

```
$ipaddress = <ip>
$Gateway = <gateway IP>
$netadapter = <InterfaceAlias>
$primary = <First DNS record or comma seperated IP's>
$NetScript = @"
 Get-Netadapter -Name $netadapter | New-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress $IP -PrefixLength 23 -Type Unicast -DefaultGateway $Gateway
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet0' -ServerAddresses $primary
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Ethernet0" -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Ethernet0" -DisplayName "QoS Packet Scheduler"
"@
$NetScript = $NetScript.Replace('#netadapter#', $netadapter).Replace('#Ipaddress#', $IP).Replace('#Gateway#', $Gateway)

#Where Ethernet0 = InterfaceAlias
```

Use this alot in Vmware and HyperV deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Set custom DNS server for IPv4 and IPv6 for every 'UP' adapter. (all customizable)

```
# Quad9 DNS servers
$Ipv4PrimaryDns = '9.9.9.9'
$Ipv4BackupDns = '149.112.112.112'
$Ipv6PrimaryDns = '2620:fe::fe'
$Ipv6BackupDns = '2620:fe::9'

Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object Status -eq 'Up' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $_.ifIndex -ServerAddresses $Ipv4PrimaryDns, $Ipv4BackupDns, $Ipv6PrimaryDns, $Ipv6BackupDns
}

Clear-DnsClientCache
```